# How to get zsh to not recognize the asterisk in apt-get

Tags: linux, apt, zsh

I am currently on Pop!OS 20.04, and after installing zsh and setting it as my default shell, when installing apps by using apt-get like follows, zsh says no matches found:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install libreoffice* -y
```

Why does this happen, and is there a way to make this not happen again?

Comment: Damn, looks like I haven't found far enough.

Comment: Probably you should write `sudo apt-get install libreoffice'*'` (note the apostrophes).